# Apt update fails with bionic release no longer has a release file (Mariadb)

Tags: apt, mariadb, ubuntu-18.04

Tried to update the apt cache with `sudo apt update` and it failed with:

> The repository 'http://mirror1.imageworld.fi/pub/mariadb/repo/10.4/ubuntu bionic Release' no longer has a Release file

Environment:

- Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
- MariaDB 10.4.12

How do I get around this?

TIA.

Comment: I have no idea. :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That URL does not contain a valid MariaDB mirror. It appears to return 404 for pretty much everything except the host's homepage.

Go back to MariaDB's web site and [select a valid mirror](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/).